# Android make progressbar background color opacity 100%

Tags: java, android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am setting up a progressbar background color to a specific blue `#00B0F0`

When I look at the progressbar the color shows up as with as a faded version of the desired color.

I imagine that the progressBackgroundTintList sets a the background color with less opacity.

I'm setting up the progressBar.progressBackgroundTintList this way:

```
    progressBar.progressBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(context?.resources.getColor(R.color.blue, null))
```

Here is what's in my XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to set the progressBar.progressBackgroundTintList as a full color

Comment: have you tried #FF00B0F0 ? the first byte is for alpha channel transparency.

Comment: Sadly I have, but it didn't resolve my issue.